# Xamarin - Remote Mac emulation

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows 10 machine and have developed a simple Xamarin app.
I've got a Mac mini, with XCode on it, on the same network.
In VS when I select the IOS project and choose debug the Mac mini successfully pairs to the Windows machine. However, nothing is displaying or shows up on the Mac mini.

My understanding is I'd see the app running or being emulated on the Mac at this point.
I'm not getting any error messages on either box or in VS.

Thanks.

Comment: The simulator should either show on the mac mini or on your Windows PC depending on whether you have enabled the Remote Simulator in Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS Settings. Make sure you have started xcode on the mac at least once to install the command-line tools

Comment: Do you mean to display the deployment on both mac and windows? Please check the 'Remote Simulator to Windows' option to deploy on windows. And try opening the 'Simulator' application on the mac, the deployment will also be shown.

Comment: No doctor can name the illness without symptom. Check your output in VS, change log level settings, give some screenshots about your build settings or the screens after deploying your app.